# Got someone Blazor remote validation to work?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I tried to get remote validation with Blazor working.
There are currently no Blazor Examples in the Internet.

I configured my controller / remote attribute like described in the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#remote-attribute

My blazor code looks like this

```
<EditForm EditContext="@_editContext" > 
   <ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator/>
   <ValidationMessage  For="@(() => User.Email)"/>
   <InputText class="text" type="text" placeholder="Email*" @bind Value="User.Email"/>
</EditForm>
```

I got no errors.
There is no request going out and no validation is gonna be executed.

Dont know whats missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use DataAnnotation Remote attribute with Blazor. You may use FluentValidation instead. Here's [a link](https://jonhilton.net/blazor-client-server-validation-with-fluentvalidation/) to an article explaining how to do that.

Note: This `@bind Value="User.Email"` should be @bind-Value="User.Email"

Hope this works...